# vlcj freezed at local when it is streaming

Tags: vlcj

I'm working with vlcj, there i combined CaptureTest and StreamRtpDuplicate to achieve streaming from a capture device.

streaming from a capture device is working fine at the receiver end with 4-6 seconds delay,but local display got frozen at the first frame.

we are trying with manually entered option showing bellow,

mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, ":dshow-size=1280*720", ":dshow-fps=24", ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts, dst=192.168.1.13:10000},dst=display}", ":sout-all", ":sout-keep") ;

where media = "dshow://"

system specifications:
                      Windows 10 64 bit
                      RAM : 4GB
                      Processor : i5-7400
                      Java version : 32 bit 1.8.0_161
                      JRE : 1.8.0_161-b12
                      Eclipse : oxygen 2 
                      VLCj : 3.11.0
                      VLC : 2.1.5 Rincewind 32 bit
                      Capture Device : Logitech HD ProWebcam C920

Console part:

[185cf584] x264 encoder: profile High, level 3.1

[185cf584] x264 encoder: final ratefactor: 30.29

[swscaler @ 22df4c00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[185cf584] x264 encoder: using SAR=3/4

[185cf584] x264 encoder: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2

[185cf584] x264 encoder: profile High, level 3.1

[268690bc] main vout display error: Failed to set on top
[268690bc] main vout display error: Failed to resize display
[22ec6adc] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[22ec6adc] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
[22ec6adc] avcodec decoder error: more than 5 seconds of late video -> dropping frame (computer too slow ?)
.
.
.
.

when media file is streamed both local and receiver display is working fine

Please help me out to fixing the local display issue without disturbing receiver end.

Comment: Does it stream fine if you use the same options in VLC?

Comment: Yes. Same options works well in VLC. This option string is generated from VLC itself.